# JAX-RS Client using Server Side Events prints the same items without completing

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a service written in Spring WebFlux which is returning a Flux of items via SSE. When I curl the URL the events are displayed and the command exits. I am trying to use the JAX-RS client code below to do the same.

The code executes and displays all the items but never exits. Once the event for the final item has been displayed it starts again with the first. The event handler for the complete event is never called.

```
fun loadAll() {
    val target = client.target(baseURL)
    val source = SseEventSource
        .target(target)
        .build()

    val onEvent = { event: InboundSseEvent ->
        println(event)
    }
    val onError = { _: Throwable ->
        println("onError")
    }
    val onComplete = {
        println("onComplete")
        source.close()
    }

    source.register(onEvent, onError, onComplete)
    source.open()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that:

1. Later versions of Jersey automatically reconnect when the connection is dropped
2. The correct behaviour in SSE on a reconnection is to resend all the items (assuming a finite sequence of items)

So it would appear that when the server finishes sending items neither the error or complete callbacks are triggered and instead the connection is re-established, which in turn resends all the items.

I was able to get what I wanted using an alternative pattern from the Jersey documentation:

```
fun loadAll() {
    val target = client.target(baseURL)
    val input = target.request().get(EventInput::class.java)
    while(!input.isClosed) {
        val inboundSseEvent = input.read()
        if(inboundSseEvent != null) {
            val thing = inboundSseEvent.readData(Thing::class.java, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            process(thing)
        }
    }
}
```